# Bitmap-Image-Mat manipulation in emgucv : Overflow for imageSize

Tags: c#, emgucv, mat

I would like to ask for some help which could lead me to understand Mat, Image and Bitmaps. I'm using [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/) in C# and I would like to convert the captured desktop screen ( which is bitmap ) to mat. I found some advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27281427/how-to-convert-bitmap-to-mat-structur-in-emgucv-how-to-detect-two-images-shift), but it didn't work for me.

What I would like to do is to convert the bitmap to image, the image to mat, then the mat back to image and the image back to bitmap, so that I can stream it to a picturebox. The problem is that when I'm converting from mat to image there is an exception thrown :

[image]

As I can see, there was a problem during converting the image to mat, as the rows (width) of the mat is exceptionally huge.

[image]

Here is the code I'm using.

```
public void Video()
{
      int Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
      int Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
      Size size = new Size(Height, Width);
      for ( ; ; )
      {
          System.Drawing.Image image;
          Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Width, Height );

          Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image);
          graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, Width, Height, bitmap.Size);

          Image<Bgr, Byte> imageCV = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(bitmap);

          //  CvInvoke.BitwiseNot(imageCV1, imageCV2, null);
          Mat m = new Mat(Height, Width , DepthType.Cv8U , 4);
          m = imageCV.Mat;

          Image<Bgr, Byte> mToImage = m.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();  //error line

          //   Bitmap btm = mToImage.ToBitmap();
          Bitmap btm = mToImage.ToBitmap(m.Height, m.Width);

          pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
          pictureBox1.Image = btm;

          imageCV.Dispose(); 
          mToImage.Dispose();
     }
}
```

I know similar questions have been asked, and maybe I should have been able to put the pieces together, but I ran out of ideas. I tried to set the size of the Mat too, so the number of the rows cannot get too high, I also tried to invert my bitmap before passing it to an image. If anyone could help me to understand the concept behind them and this problem, I would be glad.

Answer (score 1):

I've got to solve the problem with simply creating a new project and re-adding the necessary libraries again. The problem was I didn't added them correctly to my project. ( Emgu.CV.World.dll, Emgu.CV.UI.dll and the other dlls, which can be found in EmguCV's build folder.)